# Spring.Net inject into instantiated windows service? Is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, code-injection, spring.net

I have a windows service that uses top shelf and in the main method of the service I have,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //TopShelf
            if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
            {
                var host = HostFactory.New(
                        x =>
                        {
                            x.Service<MyWindowsSvcHost>(
                                s =>
                                {
                                    s.ConstructUsing(name => new MyWindowsSvcHost());
                                    s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start(null));
                                    s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());
                                });
                            x.RunAsLocalSystem();
                            x.SetDescription("SomeServiceName");
                            x.SetDisplayName("SomeServiceName");
                            x.SetServiceName("SomeServiceName");

                        });
                host.Run();

                Environment.ExitCode = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new MyWindowsSvcHost() };
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
            }
        }
```

I am using spring to inject into static property of this service. Inside MyWindowsSvcHost I have a static property myStaticProperty that I would like to spring load into. The following is how my service app.config looks like

```
<object id="SomeName" singleton="false" type="MyWindowsSvcHostAssembly.MyWindowsSvcHost, MyWindowsSvcHostAssembly">
        <property name="MyStaticProperty" ref="myStaticObject" />
      </object>

      <object id="myStaticObject" singleton="true" type="SomeAssembly.MyStaticClass, SomeAssembly">
      </object>
```

And inside the service, I have the property

public static SomeClass MyStaticProperty { get; set; }

But this is always null. If I change the singleton below to true and debug it, it always gets assigned correctly and everything works.

```
<object id="SomeName" singleton="true" type="MyWindowsSvcHostAssembly.MyWindowsSvcHost, MyWindowsSvcHostAssembly">
            <property name="MyStaticProperty" ref="myStaticObject" />
          </object>
```

Any idea what is happening behind the scenes here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this turned out to be simple. When I start the service,

```
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new MyWindowsSvcHost() };
```

Instead of creating a new instance, I had to resolve it to spring loaded instance.